# HTML CSS Table border color issue for row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

```css
.table-content {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-content table tr th {
    font-weight: 500;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
tr {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
}
th {
    background: rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
    padding: 15px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
    color: $dark-text;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
  <div class="table-content">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="1"></th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th rowspan="1"></th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>
                                <img src="/assets/images/img-placeholder.svg" >
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>keychain</td>
                        <td>200</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>Ordered</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td>Invoiced</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td>Shipped</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td>Returned</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

There is border-bottom-color which I want to make the same as other borders in this case the first row of the table has the same border-bottom-color property as other tr's but in the first row, I had added td such as image, rate, discount so the problem is the bottom border color is a bit darker than the other tr border. how can I achieve the same border color..?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug may happen with Chrome or Opera when you might have some colspan that are empty.
So either you choose a grey color directly without opacity as it is coming from opacaity.

Either you use the trick as below with box-shadow.

```
tr {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
}
```

I also customize property for `tr:first-child` and `tr:last-child`. to keep border normaly and not using box shadow

Demo:

```css
.table-content {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-content table tr th {
    font-weight: 500;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
tr:first-child, tr:last-child{
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
}
tr {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
}
th {
    background: rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
    padding: 15px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
    color: $dark-text;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-content">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="1"></th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th rowspan="1"></th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>
                                <img src="/assets/images/img-placeholder.svg" >
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>keychain</td>
                        <td>200</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>Ordered</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td>Invoiced</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td>Shipped</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td>Returned</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong with the CSS, but if you fill in the entire table, it should be gone.

```css
.table-content {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-content table tr th {
    font-weight: 500;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
tr {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
}

th {
    background: rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
    padding: 15px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
    color: $dark-text;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-content">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="1"></th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th rowspan="1"></th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                                <img src="/assets/images/img-placeholder.svg" >
                        </td>
                        <td>keychain</td>
                        <td>200</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>Ordered</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                                <img src="/assets/images/img-placeholder.svg" >
                        </td>
                        <td>keychain</td>
                        <td>200</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>Ordered</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                                <img src="/assets/images/img-placeholder.svg" >
                        </td>
                        <td>keychain</td>
                        <td>200</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>Ordered</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>
                                <img src="/assets/images/img-placeholder.svg" >
                        </td>
                        <td>keychain</td>
                        <td>200</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>Ordered</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't happen in Firefox. I suspect it's a bug in Chrome having to do with unrendered cells. Cells that are empty don't render which is why you often see them filled with `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.table-content {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-content table tr th {
    font-weight: 500;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
tr {
}
th {
    background: rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
    padding: 15px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(38, 46, 46, 0.2);
    color: $dark-text;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1rem;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-content">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="1"></th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th rowspan="1"></th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>
                                <img src="/assets/images/img-placeholder.svg" >
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>keychain</td>
                        <td>200</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>Ordered</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td>Invoiced</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td>Shipped</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td>Returned</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td colspan="1"></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I solve the problem... I think the colour code is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Use something like this

```
tr{
border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
```

Works for me.